# How to display different content in a FlatList

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-native-flatlist

I'm currently stuck on a problem that I don't know how to solve properly.

I want to create a feed for the start page of my app. The feed should be infinitely scrollable and as resource-efficient as possible.
Of course, this can all be done with the FlatList Component, but I don't know how to display different types of components in the FlatList.

Here is a picture with an example of how I mean different types of components:

[Example of complex layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iIpW5.png)

So the layout has to be very flexible and I don't know how to do that with a FlatList.
I have already thought about conditional rendering, but again I am missing a way of making it work correctly.

Have any of you ever solved such a problem? I would be grateful for any suggestions!

Comment: you can assign type to all distinct component/ list items and on load assign different style class depending on type of item.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a component that returns your different types of content dynamically, for example:

```
const mock = [
  {
    type: 'feed_1',
    title: 'Lorem',
    feed: [],
  },
  {
    type: 'feed_2',
    title: 'Ipsum',
    feed: [],
  }
]

function App() {
  return (
    <FlatList
      data={mock}
      renderItem={(item) => <Dynamic item={item} />}
    />
  );
}

const Dynamic = memo(({item}) => { 
  switch (item.type) {
    case 'feed_1':
      return <ComponentForFeed1 data={item} />
    case 'feed_2':
      return <ComponentForFeed2 data={item} />

    default:
      return null;
  }
})
```

You should also use `memo` on your "Dynamic" component to prevent unnecessary renders, don't take the above code to literal, it's just a draft of what you can do to change the render dynamically.

Also you can get similar characteristics of your sections and put them on the Dynamic component, this way you just change the actual content.

Comment: First of all, thank you very much for your detailed answer. 

I have already thought about your approach, but I always had doubts whether it was really the right approach. And I hadn't really found any useful information on this topic.

Using Memo is really a very useful tip, I hadn't thought about it before. 

Do you think that this approach has a bad influence on the performance? Because I can't set the getItemLayout prop, for example. But again: Thank you very much :)

Comment: No worries, so about the getItemLayout, yes you will not be able to easily compute the item height but its possible if each section of your list has a predefined height you can compute that using a switch just like the Dynamic component, in any case I don't think the lack of getItemLayout will get your performance, as it influences very large lists and by the looks of your layout you have fewer elements with long content. And you have other performance trick like removeClippedSubviews that clear memory for unseen alements on the screen. Success on your project.

Comment: Oh, another thing to lookup for performance gains is to use the right image sizes, using big images and just resizing them to fit the holders can be very memory expensive, make sure to use thumbs of small size already cropped so your list can render fast. Saw a lot of projects suffering from that in the past.